# How do I present a "share", "open in" and built-in and custom actions in a single menu?

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, uidocumentinteraction

In the app that I am working on, the user can add and remove photos of buildings, and interact with those photos.  I am looking for a solution which will present the user with:

1. "share" options for images
2. "open in" options for image files
3. built-in activities for images such as copy and print
4. custom activities such as delete

Using a `UIDocumentInteractionController`, I can give the user 1, 2, and 3.  Using `UIActivityViewController`, I can give them 1, 3 and 4.

I've seen workarounds which present a `UIActivityViewController` with an "Open in..." custom activity, which then shows a `UIDocumentInteractionController`, but this shows 1 and 3 to the user twice, which makes the app look shoddy.

How do I show 1-4 in a single activity menu?